# keys() method of a Python dictionary return ordered list or not

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Using Python 2.7. Want to confirm that we cannot assume .keys() method returns keys of a dictionary (as a list) in an ordered way (e.g. ascending order)? Tried a few samples, and always return ordered list, so want to double confirm. Python official document does not mention order related stuff.

Comment: We can confirm that the list returned by .keys is ordered

Comment: @Liam, thanks and vote up, could you point me the official document? I searched but not see related stuff mentioned.

Comment: Could you update the title to include the question, as it stands, it's a little vague.

Comment: I haven't looked for an official document but it is crystal clear that it is ordered, I'll search a document anyways

Comment: @TankorSmash, done, and vote up for your advice. If you have any thoughts on my original question, it will be great. :)

Comment: @LinMa Found the docs for keys, which links to items, which says it's not ordered.

Comment: @Liam, thanks and vote up, I search here (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), but not see it is mentioned keys are ordered list.

Comment: @TankorSmash, thanks and vote up. I searched here (https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys), I do not see it is explicitly mention order or not ordered. Where do you see it is explicitly mentioning keys are not ordered?

Comment: Look here https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: @Liam  Um.. keys are not ordered, so it's not crystal clear.

Comment: @Liam, vote up. Thanks for confirming it is not ordered. :)

Comment: @Brendanabel looks like I was wrong

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

> CPython implementation detail: Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

No, you cannot rely on the ordering to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks TankorSmash, vote up. And will mark it as answer in 7 mins. :))

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys tells you to see the notes for `dict.items` which contains the note.

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html:

> The keys() method of a dictionary object returns a list of all the keys used in the dictionary, in arbitrary order (if you want it sorted, just apply the sorted() function to it).